# Problem involving summing exponential series:

Tags: summation, intuition, trigonometric-series, exponential-sum

[image]

I can show the first part (i) (a), but the second part (b) i think it should be $S=\infty$ since the denominator is zero with that value of $\theta$. However, this is not the answer, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The sum cannot be infinite as it only has 10 terms. You must take the limit for $\theta\to2n\pi$, or compute directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, $$1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=10.$$
Alternatively, denoting $z=e^{i\theta}$,
$$S=\frac{z^{\frac12}(z^{10}-1)}{z^{\frac12}-z^{-\frac12}}=\frac{z(z^{10}-1)}{z-1}.$$
By L'Hospital,
$$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}=\lim_{z\to1}10z^{9}.$$
Or, if you want to do it the hard way,
$$\lim_{\theta\to2n\pi}\frac{e^{i\frac\theta2}(e^{i10\theta}-1)}{2i\sin\frac\theta2}
=\lim_{\theta\to2n\pi}\frac{\frac i2e^{i\frac\theta2}(e^{i10\theta}-1)+i10e^{\frac i2\theta}e^{i10\theta}}{i\cos\frac\theta2}=\frac{\frac i2(-1)^n(1-1)+i10(-1)^n1}{i(-1)^n}=10.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\theta=2n\pi$, $e^{ki\theta}=e^{2\pi(nk)i}=1$ if $k\in\Bbb Z$. Thus we have
$$S=10.$$